# How to send percentage of task completion without closing connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm working with .net to provide REST api for my app. I'm trying to do the following:
import some big bunch of data from client side from csv file (~100K records) and process it on the server. Since processing can take some time I would like to provide user with percentage of the task completion. The question is how to do it using post request which uploaded the file without closing the connection?

Is that possible to send several responses before sending complete?

Due to requirements I can't use such things as websockets, only REST api.
I guess that I can do something like longpolling or just make small requests for the percentage with some time interval, but it would be nice to find some simplier alternative solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of Pubnub to do that. You can send to server your csv file and some unique id of channel name. Subscribe to this channel on client and you can publish from server messages about the task progress to this unique id name (channel). Read this documentation: [pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/c-sharp-dot-net-c-sharp/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe)